# Multiple Receivers in a command's execute method in command Design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, command

I have a command which implements the `execute()` method defined in `ICommand` interface. I need to call actions which are defined in multiple receivers. How do we instantiate multiple receiver objects in the `execute()` method? Can we use multiple receivers in a single Command object?

I need to instantiate 2 receivers and call a method in each receiver from the `execute()` method.

```
void execute() {
    receiver1.do();
    receiver2.do2();
}
```

Comment: Show what you mean, this is unclear

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call multiple methods which exist in the scope where the command was instantiated. You can pass a method into the MethodToExecute parameter which calls multiple methods. eg:

```
myCommand = new Command(
    //MethodToExecute
    () => { method1(); method2(); method2(); },
    //MethodToDetectCanExecute
    () => { return true; }
);
```

Comment: I need to instantiate 2 receivers and call the methods in each receiver from execute method.Eg:  void Execute(){ receiver1.do(); receiver2.do2();  }

Answer (score 0):

In the command design pattern the Command object knows about the receiver by [aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation). If you create the receiver objects in the Command object, then that is composition. The receiver objects should be able to exist without the Command objects (loose coupling). You should rather pass the receiver objects as parameters to the Command constructor (in client code).